# Helps on Chrome timeline data and what next

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have used tools like WPT, Page Speed, which is high level suggestions.  And recently I'm trying to did some performance investigation for our frontend using Chrome timeline data for fine grain detail.

I understand the Layout Paint cycle, and FPS concept.  And I went through the Google doc on Chrome timeline section, but it is very high level information.

## **Question**

But once you see the timeline "flames" graph, how do you spot where is the problem or how do I know if I'm looking at the right problem. I want to apply this knowledge into more real world scenario instead of just understanding the concept.

Thanks for any advice :)

## **Reference Images[image]**

[image]